# Multiple rewrite rules htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web

I would like to redirect my homepage :

> - / =>/app/index.php

And

> - /rep/ => /app/rep.php
> - /rep/new/ => /app/page/rep/rep_add.php
> - /rep/([0-9]*)/ => /app/rep.php

And

> - /ouv/ => /app/parc.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/ => /app/parc.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/ => /app/parc.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*) / => /app/parc.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/  => /app/ouv.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/  =>  /app/page/ouv/bdc.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/new/  =>   /app/page/ouv/bdc_add.php
> - /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/([0-9]*)/bdr/  =>    /app/page/ouv/bdr.php

And define error 404

This is my .htaccess, but they don’t work and i don’t understand why.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /app/page/error/404.php
DirectoryIndex /app/index.php
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule  rep/ /app/rep.php
RewriteRule  rep/([0-9]*)/ /app/rep.php
RewriteRule  rep/new/ /app/page/rep/rep_add.php

RewriteRule  /ouv/ /app/parc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/ /app/parc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/ /app/parc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/ /app/parc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/  /app/ouv.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/  /app/page/ouv/bdc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/([0-9]*)/   /app/page/ouv/bdc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/new/   /app/page/ouv/bdc_add.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/bdc/([0-9]*)/bdr/   /app/page/ouv/bdr.php
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1` catches everything, and rewrite rules rewrite what is rewritten by this rule, so rep/ becomes app/rep/, etc.

Move that rule to the end and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Ok , i delete this rules , it's work for "rep" , "rep/25" , but no for "rep/new".

Comment: beacause your rule defines rewrite for `rep/new/`, not for `rep/new`. To get rep/new working, change `rep/new/` in your rule to `rep/new/?`

Answer (score 0):

For RewriteRule you must define start and end of your rules for better detection.

```
RewriteRule  /ouv/ /app/parc.php
RewriteRule  /ouv/([0-9]*)/ /app/parc.php
```

cause redirection of every things on */ouv/* to */app/parc.php* in first rule. so */ouv/566/* for example would be redicted to */app/parc.php566/* .

To prevent this situation you must define end of rule also starting point of rule.

```
RewriteRule  ^/ouv/$ /app/parc.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^/ouv/([0-9]*)/$ /app/parc.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also I recommend you to use  [NC,QSA,L] flags too.